# Next channel in Pipe Filter design not being invoked - Spring Integration

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new to Spring integration and am basically just trying to learn. I am trying to implement the a pipe filter design. The idea is to send a message to a channel where a particular message endpoint processes the message and passes it to the next channel. Here is my spring config

```
<int:gateway id="instanceRequest" service-interface="com.trivialjava.rnd.spring_inttest.RequestProcessor"/>

<!-- each request is checked for type and sent to proper channel  -->
<int:channel id="requests"/>
<int:splitter input-channel="requests" expression="payload.request" output-channel="requestData"/>

<int:channel id="requestData"/>
<int:router input-channel="requestData"  expression="payload.class.name">
    <int:mapping value="com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.InstanceRequest" channel="instanceRequests"/>
    <int:mapping value="com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.SolutionRequest" channel="solutionRequests"/>
</int:router>

<!-- instanceRequests are processed by the filter one -->
<int:channel id="instanceRequests">
    <int:queue capacity="20"/>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="instanceRequests" ref="instanceRequestNameHandler" method="prepareName" output-channel="instanceRequestsDesc"/>

<!-- instanceRequestsDesc are processed by the filter two -->
<int:channel id="instanceRequestsDesc">
    <int:queue capacity="20"/>
</int:channel>
<int:service-activator input-channel="instanceRequestsDesc" ref="instanceRequestDescHandler" method="prepareDesc" />

<beans:bean id="instanceRequestNameHandler" class="com.trivialjava.rnd.spring_inttest.InstanceNameRequestProcessor"/>

<beans:bean id="instanceRequestDescHandler" class="com.trivialjava.rnd.spring_inttest.InstanceDescRequestProcessor"/>
```

I have Request interface, and two implementations InstanceRequest and SolutionRequest. We can ignore the Solution Request for the time being.

Here are is my InstanceRequest handlers

```
public class InstanceNameRequestProcessor {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InstanceNameRequestProcessor.class);

public String prepareName(InstanceRequest request) {

        System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " request name #" + request.getName() );
        logger.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()
                + " request name #" + request.getName() );
        return request.getDescription();

}
}
```

and

```
public class InstanceDescRequestProcessor {

private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(InstanceDescRequestProcessor.class);

public String prepareDesc(String request){
    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()
            + " request desc #" + request );
    logger.info(Thread.currentThread().getName()
            + " request desc #" + request );
    return request;
}

}
```

Now when i am invoking the gateway passing an InstanceRequest, only the first channel for InstanceRequest i.e instanceRequests is being invoked but not the second channel i.e instanceRequestsDesc. In the logs i can see messages like

```
13:54:09.077 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.router.ExpressionEvaluatingRouter] Channel mappings:{} replaced with:{com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.InstanceRequest=instanceRequests, com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.SolutionRequest=solutionRequests}
13:54:15.334 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] preSend on channel 'instanceRequests', message: GenericMessage [payload=com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.InstanceRequest@632da81b, headers={timestamp=1429898055334, id=6eada370-486c-7ab8-23df-38836782c846, correlationId=b0138751-8154-ff87-b2e2-dc5f8b2381d3, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=1}]
13:54:15.334 DEBUG [main][org.springframework.integration.channel.QueueChannel] postSend (sent=true) on channel 'instanceRequests', message: GenericMessage [payload=com.trivialjava.rnd.entity.InstanceRequest@632da81b, headers={timestamp=1429898055334, id=6eada370-486c-7ab8-23df-38836782c846, correlationId=b0138751-8154-ff87-b2e2-dc5f8b2381d3, sequenceSize=1, sequenceNumber=1}]
```

But there are no logs which suggests that the second channel as been initialised. Have i missed something, some configuration or some known design issue in Spring Integration.

Comment: I don't see anything specific in your config and your code. I guess there is some Exception in your log, but it isn't obvious where. I'd recommend you get rig of `<queue>` and try your solution just with `DirectChannel`s. In this case an exception will be thrown to you caller: the `RequestProcessor` initiator.

Comment: Thanks @ArtemBilan for your inputs. It was a big mistake on my part. The above was not an issue at all. I had put debug point on the handler InstanceNameRequestProcessor. And since it is a QueueChannel and a separate thread waits at that debug point, and i didn't see there are other suspended threads.